# Multiclass classification going wrong with Python Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to realize a little comparative between the classifiers available in Scikit-learn.
According to [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html), all classifiers should work except the svm one.

This operation is implemented as follows :

```py
clf['bayes'] = OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(
clf['lda'] = OneVsRestClassifier(LDA())
clf['decision tree'] = OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())
clf['rdc'] = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier())
```

```py
y_supposes = {}
precision = {}
for classifier in clf:
    clf[classifier].fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_supposes[classifier] = clf[classifier].predict(x_test)
    precision[classifier] = calcul_precision(y_supposes[classifier], y_test)
```

The trouble is, the only working classifier is the `bayes`classifier.

The other give me this error when I try to call `classifier['rdc'].fit(x_train, y_train)` :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 201, in fit
    n_jobs=self.n_jobs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 92, in fit_ov
r
    for i in range(Y.shape[1]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 517, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 312, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", lin
e 136, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\multiclass.py", line 61, in _fit_b
inary
    estimator.fit(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 257, in
fit
    check_ccontiguous=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 220, in
 check_arrays
    raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray
() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

I'd like to add that `clf['rdc'].fit(x_train.toarray, y_train)` (as indicated in the error message) also gives me an error.

Could you please help me find the step I skipped ?

### Edit : New developments

I think the trouble might come from the type of `x_train`. I compute it as follows :

```
x = [{f1 : a, ... fn : jo}, ..., {f3 : 5}]
y_train = [('label1', ), ..., ('labelZ', 'label72')]
x_train = DictVectorizer.fit_transform(x)

type(x_train) ==  <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

I also tried this approach : `MultinomialNB.fit(np.array(x), np.array(y))` which gives me a new error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 308, in fit
X = X.astype(np.float)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message quite clearly indicates, you're passing a sparse matrix to an estimator that doesn't support those. Of the four classifiers you test, only `MultinomialNB` supports sparse matrix inputs. For decision trees and random forests, sparse matrix support is work in progress.

As for `np.array(x)`, that doesn't do what you think it does. To convert a sparse matrix to a dense array, use `x.toarray()`, or just pass `sparse=False` to the `DictVectorizer` constructor.